# Qt frameless window with translucent background without error "UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed"

Tags: qt, qwindow

Since some time I get an error like `UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=...` for my frameless window with rounded corners: I set my main window frameless and draw an inner widget with rounded corners.

There is a discussion at Qt [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52206) and the code for the warning has been added [here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/143255/2/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowsbackingstore.cpp). They say:

> So, yes, this was silently failing all the time. It is a restriction
>   on Windows that translucency (WS_EX_LAYERED) only works for frameless
>   toplevel windows.

However, I only set translucency on my main top level window:

```
if (m_isMainApplicationWindow && CGuiUtility::isTopLevelWindow(m_widget)) {
  m_widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow);
  m_widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, frameless);
  m_widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, frameless); // causing QTBUG-52206
}
```

So how do I do it right and avoid the error?

---

Impression how it looks like:
[image: Frameless window rounded corner]

Comment: Set shadow setting to frames or any widgets inside the main window or dialog. It isn't recommended to add it to Dialog or MainWindow directly.